# Posting Dictionary<string, object> without receiving valuekind?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, blazor

I'm building some generic stored procedure service in blazor wasm.

I'm preparing object `Dictionary<string, object>`:

```
public async Task ExecProc()
{
    parameters=await this.ihttp.Post<Dictionary<string, object?>>("api/GSP/ExecProc/"+this.ProcedureName, parameters);
}
```

so it is for example key: `'v_str1_o'` and value `test`

like on screen values in debug when sending, and sending it to API  with my params:

[image: prepared object]

But when I receive it in the API:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("ExecProc/{SPname}")]
public IActionResult ExecProc(string SPname, [FromBody] Dictionary<string, object?> parameters)
```

and receive it as same key but value like  `ValueKind = String : "test"`

In the screenshot how it looks in debug - values with additional valuekind markup :

[image: after api receive]

I know that from .NET Core 3.0 there is a new JSON serializer by Microsoft, but I don't want this valuekind stuff. I want the raw values as I sent them.

Is there any way to do this without installing Newtonsoft Json ?
I know how to do it with Newtonsoft - I'm using same solution in some other projects, but my goal this time was to not use this library as .NET Core has its own fast serializer / deserializer now.